# Submitting offline forms using python

Tags: python, html

I am trying to extract information from my college website using python. Here is the link of the website.

http://studzone.psgtech.edu/CommonPage.aspx

I have the exam results page locally saved. I want to know how to submit data using the local file and get the resulting page using python. I've looked into urllib2, requests, mechanize frameworks. But haven't got any useful information on submitting data from a local HTML file. Thanks in advance.

Back note: The reason I saved it locally is, the website uses a specific token for each detail such as Time-Table, Results, etc. So we need to send requests from that specific page such as Time-Table, Results. i.e. A student can access only one detail at a time and there is no separate page for that.

Edit:

I've use following code to obtain the web page and store it in a object. Is there anyway to post the form in that webpage stored in the page variable? I can edit the field such that value="something".

```
import urllib2
import requests

page = urllib2.urlopen("http://google.com/").read()
c = requests.post(page, data) //is something like this possible?
```

Comment: how do you access that page on your computer - with file:/// ?

Comment: var = open("filename")

Comment: I actually don't know to submit forms in context of file protocol, but if you move it to any local server, you can send data with post method. 
of course if external requests  are not disallowed by server. 

or if you have a token or something, you can send it directly to  actual url. 
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/
after authentication step, `requests.post(url, data={'k1':'v1', 'k2':'v2'})` will act normally.

Comment: i do not need any authentication. I just need to enter a student id in the textbox and hit submit. this should return the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 files. `login.php`, `auth.php`, `index.php`. 
Direct access to `index.php` is disabled. If user is not authenticated, request for `index.php` is redirected to `login.php`.

```
>>> url = 'http://127.0.0.1/adminpanel/admin/index.php'
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get(url)
>>> print r.text

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Login </title>
</head>
<body>
        <form method="POST" action="auth.php">
            <input type="text" name="username">
            <input type="password" name="password">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">                  
        </form>


</body>
</html>
>>> print r.url
http://127.0.0.1/adminpanel/admin/login.php
```

There is no authentication logic in login.php it is just a form. The authentication process is held in auth.php. Let's send a post request with some data to this url.

```
>>> auth_url = "http://127.0.0.1/adminpanel/admin/auth.php"
>>> params = {'username':'superadmin', 'password':'geometry123', 'submit':'submit'}
>>> r = requests.post(auth_url, data=params)
>>> print r.text[:200]



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
        Admin Panel
    </title>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="style
>>> print r.url
http://127.0.0.1/adminpanel/admin/index.php
```

So, you have to: determine names of form inputs to send a post request. If authentication will be successfull, you'll be redirected to protected page. And with other libraries (`beautifulsoup`, `urrlib3`) , you can extract the data you want.

Comment: Thank you for the example. I need to POST a field with nearly 8000 characters. When I try to submit it produces the error...

ValueError: Content-Length should be specified for iterable data of type <class 'dict'>

I tired using data= { 'id':'12ad53','key':'the long secret key')
html = urlopen(url, data)

Comment: `urlopen` from `urllib` library is not suitable for this task. it just sends a get request, and retrieves sources. you can not submit forms through `urlopen`. can you give more info about the form you want to submit? the html structure, the adress of `action` attribute etc.

Comment: I've added the link of the website I want to post the details.

Comment: no, you can't do that way. as i mentioned before, urlopen is just for retrieving resources. it only sends a get request. 

for google try this. 

first,  view the source of google's search form. you'll see it sends a `get` request to `/search` and the name of input param. is 'q'. 

your query url should  be like that: google.com/search?q="lorem ipsum". so, 

`url ='http://google.com/search'; qs = {'q': 'your search term'}; r = requests.get(url, params=qs);`